# Converting existing C library to have web interface

Tags: c, web-services, axis2c

We have an existing C library (DLL / .so) that processes some data.  There's a call to initialise it, then a call to give it the parameters it needs to process, and then a few calls to retrieve the different output parameters you are interested in.  The initialise is then called to reset the library for the next session.  We have an app built around this to easily input the data and view the results.

Now we want to take this library and make it available as a web service.  We are looking for the simplest (read quickest) way to do this.  As I see it, we need:

1. A web services framework (Apache Axis2/C looks good for existing C code)
2. Some way to start a process for each incoming query (not sure if Axis2 can do something like this).

So my question is : Is Axis2/C the simplest way, or is there another simple solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an external executable you can call, how about using something like Apache with [FastCGI](http://www.fastcgi.com)?

Comment: Or just plain CGI: a little simpler/easier than FastCGI

Comment: Thanks, we will look at FastCGI.  G-WAN could be the simplest yet though.